We are trying to setup a standalone nginx reverse proxy that maps 2 separate docker-compose projects
We have two project

project-data-chatbot
project-frontend

We are trying to setup a standalone nginx reverse proxy that maps 2 separate docker-compose projects, the backend is working on a default_server configuration but trying to setup proxy_pass to the front-end project is not working
Dockerfile details on project-frontend
FROM php:8.1-fpm

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
        nodejs \
        npm \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo \
    && docker-php-ext-install pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && docker-php-source delete \

COPY . /var/www/html

COPY ./.env /var/www/html/.env

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

EXPOSE 9000 443
# EXPOSE 9000 5173 443
# EXPOSE 5173 443

# Start PHP-FPM server

docker-compose details on project-frontend
version: '3.8'

services:

#  nginx:
#    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-nginx
#    image: nginx:alpine
#    ports:
#      - "8088:80"
#    depends_on:
#      - app
#      - db
#    volumes:
#      - ./:/var/www/html
#      - ./nginx/conf.d/preprod.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
#    networks:
     # - project_frontend_network
#      - chatbot_shared_network

  app:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "5170:5170"
    expose:
      - "5170"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    networks:
     # - project_frontend_network
      - chatbot_shared_network

  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-db
    image: mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=project-frontend-db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
     # - project_frontend_network
      - chatbot_shared_network

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}-pma
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3400:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
       - chatbot_shared_network
#      - project_frontend_network

#networks:
#  project_frontend_network:
#    driver: bridge

networks:
  chatbot_shared_network:
    external: true

docker-compose.nginx.yaml for project-data-chatbot
version: '3.4'


services:
  web:
    build: nginx
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    restart: always
    environment:
      - CHATBOT_PORT=${CHATBOT_PORT}
      - CHAT_FRONTEND_PORT=${CHAT_FRONTEND_PORT}
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 81:81
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      chatbot:
        condition: service_started
  chatbot:
    expose:
      - ${CHATBOT_PORT}
      - ${CHAT_FRONTEND_PORT}

networks:
  default:
    name: chatbot_shared_network


docker-compose for project-data-chatbot
version: '3.4'


services:
  ###########
  #   App   #
  ###########

  chatbot:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - INGEST=${INGEST}
    container_name: chatbot
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      chatbot-weaviate:
        condition: service_started
      chatbot-postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - ${CHATBOT_PORT}:7860

  chatbot-postgres:
    image: postgres:16.1-bullseye
    container_name: chatbot_postgres
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${CHATBOT_POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - chatbot_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  #################
  #   Vector DB   #
  #################

  chatbot-weaviate:
    command:
    - --host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - http
    image: semitechnologies/weaviate:1.23.2
    container_name: chatbot_weaviate
    ports:
    - ${WEAVIATE_PORT}:8080
    - 50051:50051
    volumes:
    - chatbot_weaviate_data:/var/lib/weaviate
    restart: always
    environment:
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: ${WEAVIATE_QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT}
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'none'
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'

  ###############
  #   Monitor   #
  ###############

  #https://langfuse.com/docs/langflow
  # https://github.com/langfuse/langfuse/blob/main/docker-compose.yml
  langfuse-server:
    image: ghcr.io/langfuse/langfuse:2.11.0
    container_name: langfuse
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      langfuse-postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - ${LANGFUSE_PORT}:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@langfuse_postgres:5432/${LANGFUSE_POSTGRES_DB}
      - NEXTAUTH_SECRET=${NEXTAUTH_SECRET}
      - SALT=${SALT}
      - NEXTAUTH_URL=http:localhost:3000

  langfuse-postgres:
    image: postgres:16.1-bullseye
    container_name: langfuse_postgres
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${LANGFUSE_POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - langfuse_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  chatbot_pgdata:
  langfuse_pgdata:
  chatbot_weaviate_data:

networks:
  chatbot_shared_network:
    external: true

init.sh for managing containers on project-data-chatbot
#!/bin/bash

# Check if correct argument is supplied
if [ "$#" -lt 1 ] || ([ "$1" != "up" ] && [ "$1" != "down" ]); then
    echo "[ERROR]: Invalid argument. Please use 'up' or 'down'."
    exit 1
fi

# Load environment variables from .env file
export $(grep -v '^#' "./config/.env" | tr -d '\r' | xargs)

# Use Additional Modules
options=()
if [ "$NGINX" == "true" ]; then
    options+=("-f \"docker-compose.nginx.yaml\"")
fi

# Whether to start, end service
if [ "$1" = "down" ]; then
    command="docker compose --env-file \"./config/.env\" ${options[@]} -f \"docker-compose.yaml\" down"
    echo $command
    eval $command &
    wait $!
elif [ "$1" = "up" ]; then
    command="docker compose --env-file \"./config/.env\" ${options[@]} -f \"docker-compose.yaml\" up -d --build"
    echo $command
    eval $command &
    wait $!
fi

The whole idea is to use only one nginx container that is configured from the backend project and use it for the front-end too that's why we have 2 server{} blocks in the nginx config
Nginx config on project-data-chatbot
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    sendfile on;

    # upstream chatbot:${CHATBOT_PORT} {
        # server nginx:80;
        # server chatbot:${CHATBOT_PORT};
    # }

    # upstream docker-apache {
        # server apache:80;
    #}

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        # server_name project-preprod.sparktechstaging.com;
        location / {
           # proxy_pass         http://docker-nginx;
           proxy_pass           http://chatbot:${CHATBOT_PORT};
           # proxy_redirect     off;
           # proxy_set_header   Host $host;
           # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name project-preprod.sparktechstaging.com;

        root /var/www/html/public/project-frontend;
        #root /var/www/html/public;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        index index.php;

        location / {
            # proxy_pass         http://docker-apache;
            # resolver           127.0.0.11;
            # resolver           8.8.8.8;
            # root /var/www/html/public;
            # root /var/www/public;
              proxy_pass         http://project:${CHAT_FRONTEND_PORT};
            # proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            # proxy_redirect     off;
            # proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        # location ~ \.php$ {
           # fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
           # fastcgi_pass app:9000;
           # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           # include fastcgi_params;
        # }

        # location /index.php {
              # try_files $uri = 404;
              # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
              # fastcgi_pass app:9000;
              # fastcgi_pass app:5173;
              # fastcgi_index index.php;
              # include fastcgi_params;
              # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              # fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        # }
    }
}

telnet host 5170
Trying host...
Connected to host.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

if your description is right, you're running nginx on separate docker compose. you should probably import nginx config there and not inside chatbot container.
You don't need to import nginx config to your other containers.
import == volumes.

we're not importing the nginx config

Then you should in docker-compose.nginx.yaml
